# Multiple Dotfuscator build warnings Xamarin: SetStateMachine & MoveNext

Tags: xamarin.forms, dotfuscator

Dotfuscator outputs several warnings when building my Xamarin Forms Android app (.NET standard 2.0).  The following output is produced:

```
2>  Running Dotfuscator with config file 'DotfuscatorConfig.xml'...
2>EXEC : [Build Output] warning : MoveNext overrides MoveNext which could not be found.
2>EXEC : [Build Output] warning : SetStateMachine overrides SetStateMachine which could not be found.
2>EXEC : [Build Output] warning : MoveNext overrides MoveNext which could not be found.
2>EXEC : [Build Output] warning : SetStateMachine overrides SetStateMachine which could not be found.
...Repeats over and over again...
```

Has anyone else seen this and know what is going on?  Thanks,

Comment: Have you recently updated to the latest version of Dotfuscator? I updated this morning and I'm now getting this exact same combination of warnings.

Comment: I did try to update but was already getting the warnings before (I am not sure of the version I had before but it was pretty recent).

Comment: Are there any news on this warning messages?